# failed to execute servlet listener， here is the web.xml

Tags: spring, servlets

Here is the web.xml， after i run the application locally in intelli J,  i did‘t see any logs about listener loading
and it doesn't send any errors out, but when i access the controller by http request , and i found the commonData class hadn't be loading

Here is the web.xml， after i run the application locally in intelli J,  i did‘t see any logs about listener loading
and it doesn't send any errors out, but when i access the controller by http request , and i found the commonData class hadn't be loading

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <display-name>aaa-qa</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.netease.cloud.aaa.utils.CommonData</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>webContextHolderPopulateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.netease.cloud.nce.filter.WebContextHolderPopulateFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>webContextHolderPopulateFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404error</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/500error</location>
    </error-page>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file></welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Below is the console output in intelli J

```
23, 2018 3:25:14 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
 The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/sanqian/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
 23, 2018 3:25:15 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
 Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8112"]
23, 2018 3:25:15 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
 Starting service Tomcat
23, 2018 3:25:15 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
 Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
23, 2018 3:25:16 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
 No global web.xml found
23, 2018 3:25:22 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
23, 2018 3:25:22 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 Set web app root system property: 'webapp.root' = [/Users/sanqian/nce/workspace/test-code/nce-containerized-test/src/main/webapp/]
23, 2018 3:25:22 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
23, 2018 3:25:24 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
23, 2018 3:25:24 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
 Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8112"]
```